# Referential integrity errors when building Blazor in Azure Web App

Tags: .net, azure, blazor

We are working on our first Blazor app to be hosted as an Azure web app.  It builds and runs perfectly on the local machine.  If we build locally and publish from the local machine to the web app on Azure, that works fine as well.  However, when we use the deployment system in Azure to deploy from a Bitbucket repository, we get referential integrity errors after the build is done.

I've read about issues with referential integrity errors related to building locally and pushing the compiled objects up to a repository, but that is not what we are doing.  The repository holds only the source code.  I've looked at the deployment logs and it appears to be building on the remote server itself and then deploying into the wwwroot folder on that server, so there should not be an issue with the line endings getting changed.

Can anyone give us some advice about this?  The development is being done in Visual Studio 2022 if that makes a difference.

This is the message we see in the console (site name removed):

`Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://***.azurewebsites.net/_framework/icudt_EFIGS.dat' with computed SHA-256 integrity '47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='. The resource has been blocked.`

Comment: what exactly do you mean 'referential integrity' i suspect I know the answer but want to make sure we are talking the same issue. Paste error message or screen shot pls

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  Added the message in the description above.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the checksum validation on the files. I had the same issue hosting in github pages. The cause is files that had crlf being converted to cr. The checksum changes. Solution

- prevent the conversion. People suggested various ways, I could not get it to work (gitattributes to force binary file type for example)
- turn off the chekcsumming. THis is what I did

add this change

```
    // edit to prevent integrity checks messed up by github pages
    .map(asset => new Request(asset.url, {/* integrity: asset.hash, */cache: 'no-cache' }));
```

to service-worker.published.js.

In the back of my mind I think there was another change but cant find it. If this doesnt 100% fix then I will look again

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution, but I'm looking for a way to get the referential integrity checking to work rather than bypassing it or turning it off.